# How to solve $P(X=a) = P(X=b)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

A random variable X is normally distributed with $\mu = 60$ and $\sigma$ = 3. What is the value of 2 numbers a,b so that $P(X=a) = P(X=b)$.

The solution is $a = 60$ and $b = 65$.

However, I do not know how to come up with that answer. As far as I understand $P(X=a)$ and $P(X=b)$ have to be both 0 since you always have to give a range e.g. $P(a<X)$. Moreover if I insert the values 60 and 65 in the formula $Z = (X-\mu)/\sigma$ than I would end up with 0,1.667 and z-scores 0.5, 0.952 respectively.

Comment: You understand well, $P(X=a)=P(X=b)=0$, so the question is pretty meaningless.

Comment: You are correct by saying that both probabilities have to be equal to zero, since the normal distribution is continuous. Are you sure the question is stated correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is valid -- asking for $P(X=a)=P(X=b)$ makes essentially no sense because such a probability is always $0$ for a continuous distribution.

Indeed, this seems to be the only way to make $a=60, b=65$ a valid answer.

One *might* try to be charitable and "correct" the question into asking for two points where the probability *density* is the same -- but that wouldn't lead to $a=60, b=65$ being a solution; instead we would have $a=60+t, b=60-t$ for some $t$ (since the distribution is symmetric around $\mu=60$).

My tentative conclusion would be that (a) it's a trick question, (b) your understanding is correct, and (c) the solution you quote is just meant to be one *possible* answer.

Comment: It is a question from my brothers math textbook he asked me to help him with. The values $a=60$,$b=65$ are supposed to be the solution and I am trying to figure out why. But it has to be just a mistake in the book. Thank you for your help